# Convertir 2022-03-18T10:00 a formato dd/mm/yyyy JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

Buen día, tengo un `<input type="datetime-local">` que me entrega el dato de fecha en javascrip de la siguiente manera

```
2022-03-18T10:00
```

quisiera saber como puedo formatearlo de para que se vea así 18/03/2022 10:00 (hora Formato de 24hrs)

intente descomponerlo con `.slice();` sacando día mes, año, horas y min, pero cuando la hora esta por ejemplo a las 17:00 solo me imprime  `//2`

esta fecha con hora quiero compararla con otra que se ve así `2022/03/04 13:51` y validar si es mayor o menor, espero me puedan ayudar si conocen algún método, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript puede interpretar ese formato, [ver documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#several_ways_to_create_a_date_object).

Entonces:

```js
const zeroPad = (val) => val.toString().padStart(2, "0"); 
// Advertencia, padStart() -> ECMAScript 2017

let odate = new Date('2022-03-18T10:00');

let year = odate.getFullYear();
let month = zeroPad(odate.getMonth());
let day = zeroPad(odate.getDate());
let hour = zeroPad(odate.getHours());
let mins = zeroPad(odate.getMinutes());

console.log(year+'/'+month+'/'+day+' '+hour+':'+mins); // 2022/03/18 10:00
```

[ NOTA ]: No comparar fechas en formato **dd/MM/yyyy** porque saldrán resultados indeseables:

```js
console.log('18/02/2022' > '15/02/2022'); // true ¡bien!
console.log('18/02/2022' > '03/03/2022'); // true <-- X ERROR X
```

Usar el formato estándar `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, también podría servir `yyyy/MM/dd ...`, como dices que la otra fecha ya tiene el formato de la segunda forma,`2022/03/04 13:51`, entonces las puedes comparar directamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono a la perfección, gracias por tomarte el tiempo y sobre todo por la explicación